# Can I show twitter feed in bootstrap popover?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

Is it possible to display twitter feed inside bootstrap's popover? 
For example, when the twitter button is clicked I want my website's twitter feed to be displayed inside bootstrap's popover.

I've already tried the code below but is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<a href="#" role="button" class="btn popovers" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content=" <a class='twitter-timeline' data-chrome=nofooter noborders transparent data-width='250' data-height='350' href='https://twitter.com/myPage ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw'>Tweets by myPage</a>" data-original-title="test title">Test Button</a>

$("[data-toggle=popover]")
            .popover({
                html: true
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

Great Works

Try this fiddle

**HTML**

```
<h1> TWEET FEED IN BOOSTRAP POPOVER </h1>

<div><button id="target">TRY ME</button></div>

 <!-- This will be the contents of our popover -->
 <div class='_content' id='blah'>
  **** YOUR TWITTER EMBEDDED CODE *****

 </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// We don't want to see the popover contents until the user clicks the target.
// If you don't hide 'blah' first it will be visible outside of the popover.
//
$('#blah').hide();

// Initialize our popover
//
$('#target').popover({
    content: $('#blah'), // set the content to be the 'blah' div
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true
});
// The popover contents will not be set until the popover is shown.  Since we don't 
// want to see the popover when the page loads, we will show it then hide it.
//
$('#target').popover('show');
$('#target').popover('hide');

// Now that the popover's content is the 'blah' dive we can make it visisble again.
//
$('#blah').show();


});
```

**THE FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/exaland/34ykLLLr/2/

Comment: Yeah, I've already seen this and tried almost everything but nothing works.

Comment: I just make this , pls explain me or modify this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YsEqb/

Comment: What you are doing is displaying HTML inside the popover, something that I can do too. What I want is to display live twitter feed(https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines) inside that popover.

Comment: I just edited my first answer , enjoy and pls rate Me :)